# Can I disable other players from seeing my character's online status without using the appear offline toggle?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, you can basically add anyone to your friends list and see their status.

What if there are players out there that have me added to their friends list and I don't know it? How do I disable those people from seeing my online status, without having to toggle myself offline through the BattleNet app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't hide your character's online status completely. You can appear offline on bnet, which also hides your online status in the community (even your guild!), but if someone has your character on their list or just tries to find you via /who you're doomed. Luckily that only works character specific and only for people on your realm, so not everyone is able to find you.

Anyway, players from your realm will always be able to track you, so if someone is being annoying just put them on ignore.